# Django - How can i modify text before save them to database?

Tags: python, regex, database, django, sqlite

I want to input something like(via the admin page):

```
text = 't(es)t'
```

and save them as:

```
'test'
```

on database.

And I use this Regex to modify them:

```
re.sub(r'(.*)\({1}(.*)\){1}(.*)', r'\1\2\3', text)
```

I know how to transform text from `'t(es)t'` to `'test'` but the problem is

when i use

```
name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
```

to input text(from admin). It immediately save to database cannot modify it before saving.

Finally, From a single input from admin `text = 't(es)t'` (CharField).

What do i want?

1. To use `'t(es)t'` as a string variable.
2. Save `'test'` to database

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating Data in Django's Admin Panel on Save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753704/manipulating-data-in-djangos-admin-panel-on-save)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to overide the save method in your model,

```
class Model(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)

    # This should touch before saving
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = re.sub(r'(.*)\({1}(.*)\){1}(.*)', r'\1\2\3', self.name)
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Update:**

```
class Model(model.Model):
        name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
        name_org = models.CharField(max_length=16)

        # This should touch before saving
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.name = re.sub(r'(.*)\({1}(.*)\){1}(.*)', r'\1\2\3', self.name)
            self.name_org = self.name # original "t(es)t"
            super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what should i do if i have another attributes below the `name`. Will `save` method affect to my another attributes?

Comment: No it won't effects other attributes. It is customization of save method. If you want do anything before saving using this method.

Comment: Could i ask you one more question? How can i save the original text `t(es)t` to the variable is named `name_org` that i can use it later on this class?

Comment: @terces907 I have updated my answer. If it is use please accept my answer.