# How I can create a textfield in dajngo admin that not create a field in database?

Tags: django, model, admin

In django, I need a textfield and a button in django admin, but I don't want  to save that textfield in database.
For example I have a textfield named age. I need to a textfield to enter birthday.By clicking on button I will calculate age and assign to age field.
This is only a example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible by using custom ModelAdmin with a custom Form but this can be done automatically while saving the object

here is [Custom ModelAdmim Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)

Comment: Hello. Thanks. I found my soulotion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887961/django-how-can-i-modify-text-before-save-them-to-database/23888157

Comment: Can you accept answer to close the question.